# Min and max of labels repeating over a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Soooo... i have a dataframe shaped like this:

| time | label |
| --- | --- |
| 01:01 | A |
| 01:02 | A |
| 01:03 | A |
| 01:04 | C |
| 01:05 | C |
| 01:06 | A |
| 01:07 | A |
| 01:08 | A |

is there a way to separete it into an object like this?

{"A" : {min:01:01, max:01:03}, "C" : {min:01:04, max:01:05},"A" : {min:01:06, max:01:08}}

Grouping the local repetitions and getting it's min and max, for instance, the "A label repeats twice". I'd like to get the min and max of those intervals separately and transform in an object like the one above

---

what i've tryed so far is to use groupby on the label, but the end result is something like this:

{"A" : {min:01:01, max:01:08}, "C" : {min:01:04, max:01:05}}

which is different 'cause it does't keep the two intervals of "A" separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas groupby:

```
In [10]: df.groupby('label').agg({'time': [min, max]})
Out[10]:
       time
       min   max
label
A      1:01  1:08
C      1:04  1:05
```

Updated answer using `itertools.groupby`

```
In [9]: from itertools import groupby
In [10]: res = [] 
In [11]: data = list(zip(df['time'].to_list(), df['label'].to_list()))
In [12]: for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    ...:     group = list(g)
    ...:     res.append([min(group, key=lambda x: x[0]), max(group, key=lambda x: x[0])])

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
[[('1:01', 'A'), ('1:03', 'A')],
[('1:04', 'C'), ('1:05', 'C')],
[('1:06', 'A'), ('1:08', 'A')]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but it's not quite what I was looking for. You see listed as what I've tryed so far, the groupby approach returns {"A" : {min:01:01, max:01:08}, "C" : {min:01:04, max:01:05}}, not respecting the two intervals of "A", setting it as one big interval instead.

Comment: Updated using `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: That's it. THANK YOU!!!! I just need to do some changes in the output, but I think I can handle it haha

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution, assuming that the time column has the proper datetime type (if not, please share your DataFrame or the code you have used to generate it).

```
r = {}
for label, group in df.groupby('label'):
    r[label] = {'min':group['time'].min(), 'max':group['time'].max()}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but it's not quite what I was looking for. You see listed as what I've tryed so far, the groupby approach returns {"A" : {min:01:01, max:01:08}, "C" : {min:01:04, max:01:05}}, not respecting the two intervals of "A", setting it as one big interval instead.

Comment: Please, specify better what you want then, it is not clear from the question.

Comment: Ok, i've just eddited the question. Please, see if it's clearer right now.