# Need a function to calculating each species separately

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm a beginner of Python coding.

I have an exercise that use numpy to solve this Iris_df excercise.

```
    Id  sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width   species
0   1   5.1                 3.5       1.4                0.2    Iris-setosa
1   2   4.9                 3.0       1.4                0.2    Iris-setosa
2   3   4.7                 3.2       1.3                0.2    Iris-setosa
3   4   4.6                 3.1       1.5                0.2    Iris-setosa
4   5   5.0                 3.6       1.4                0.2    Iris-setosa
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
145 146 6.7                 3.0       5.2                2.3    Iris-virginica
146 147 6.3                 2.5       5.0                1.9    Iris-virginica
147 148 6.5                 3.0       5.2                2.0    Iris-virginica
148 149 6.2                 3.4       5.4                2.3    Iris-virginica
149 150 5.9                 3.0       5.1                1.8    Iris-virginica

150 rows × 6 columns
```

My exercise question is Use numpy to solve this excercise.

1. Write a function to calculate `min`, `max`, `average`, `median`, `standard deviation` of each iris feature (`sepal_length`, `sepal_width`, `petal_length`, `petal_width`)
2. Use the function from above question but calculating each species separately (`versicolor`, `setosa`, `virginica`)

With number 1, i already solve with this:

`sepal_length_array = iris_df[iris_df.columns[1:2]].to_numpy()`

`min_sepal_length = np.min(sepal_length_array)`

Anyone can help me the number 2 pls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Min and max of labels repeating over a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619594/min-and-max-of-labels-repeating-over-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: yeah, it close to my answer because i have to use numpy to calculate it

Answer (score 2):

Get to feel about `groupby()` like function.
e.g., `groupby().sum()`,`groupby().size()`,`groupby().min()`, etc.
Then you're all good to use this kind of tools in everywhere.

```
df_min = df.groupby('species').min()
df_max = df.groupby('species').max()
```

```
df_min
###
            sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
species                                                         
setosa               4.3          2.3           1.0          0.1
versicolor           4.9          2.0           3.0          1.0
virginica            4.9          2.2           4.5          1.4
```

```
df_max
###
            sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
species                                                         
setosa               5.8          4.4           1.9          0.6
versicolor           7.0          3.4           5.1          1.8
virginica            7.9          3.8           6.9          2.5
```

via `pivot_table()`
(Metrics calculate the same things)

```
df.pivot_table(index='species', values=df.columns[:4],aggfunc=[np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.median, np.std]).round(2).T
```

[image]

via `groupby()`
(Metrics could calculate different statistics).
e.g., `'sepal_length':['min','max'], 'petal_width':['median','std']`

```
statistics = ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median', 'std']
df.groupby('species').agg({'sepal_length': statistics, 'sepal_width': statistics, 'petal_length': statistics, 'petal_width': statistics}).round(2).T
```

[image]

Comment: tks for the idea but i have to convert it to numpy array like this 
`sepal_length_array = iris_df[iris_df.columns[1:2]].to_numpy()`

Then i calculate it sth like this
`min_sepal_length = np.min(sepal_length_array)`

But the question 2 is for each species

Comment: Well, would have been great if you would have given this important information before @Baron has written this extensive good answer.

Comment: oh, sorry. But it's ok. I have learn another way to solve this.

Comment: You keep saying you "have to" convert the pandas columns to a NumPy arrays first. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `groupby()` function by pandas? With this function you can group ;) a dataframe based on a given key. On top of this group you can then apply pandas `min()`, `max()` etc.

If you provide some sample data I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: I have to use numpy to calculate like this
i convert to numpy aray like this
`sepal_length_array = iris_df[iris_df.columns[1:2]].to_numpy()`
then i calculate it
`min_sepal_length = np.min(sepal_length_array)`

Comment: You can find the data set in here https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/iris/code